# Get net_rim_os not found warning when debugging

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, blackberry

Whenever I try to debug an app I am developing for the Blackberry 8xxx something,
from within Eclipse, I get this warning about net_rim_os not found.
Then I have to click away a modal, and then another with something almost the same.

I assume this is because I have only 6.x development environment installed, but the phone is 4.5.

The program works on the phone though, as long as I stay away from API not existing on the phone.

How can I make the warning never appear, or even better, install the missing symbols or whatever it is Eclipse is complaining about. It's the Eclipse provided by RIM themselves I am using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger is looking for the .debug files to support symbolic debugging. This isn't usually a problem on the simulator because it is delivered with the .debug files that match the OS. With a physical device you are faced with the issue that the OS version used on the hardware rarely, if ever, matches a version of the OS for which .debug files are available.

You will be better off compiling with an SDK version that is less than or equal to the version of the OS running on the hardware. If your testing coverage is less than complete you may end up delivering a program with a hidden API incompatability. The best practice is to compile the programs for each version of the OS you are supporting.

Comment: I think I have API coverage testing under control, so I am not worried about hidden API incompatibility. But thanks for pointing it out explicitly. Do you have any idea of where to find a toolchain for 4.5? From within Eclipse I can not seem to find any.

Comment: I don't use Eclipse for Blackberry development, and I think the support for Eclipse arrived after 4.5 so it may not be available. If I come accross something I will try to let you know, but I expect there are lots of Eclipse for Blackberry users who are better informed.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. Many just use the latest and call it a day.

Answer (score 0):

Configure Eclipse to use the [BlackBerry Update Site](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp). Then download and install the BlackBerry Java SDK 4.5. Configure your project to use that SDK. This will ensure that only APIs supported in 4.5 are available for compilation.

Comment: I have all updates now for all versions, but how do I configure the project to use one or the other?

Comment: It's in the project configuration itself. Choose the JRE version you need.

Comment: I can only choose between system JRE and the RIM 6.0 JRE. Two choices.

Comment: Did you restart Eclipse? You should see the 4.5 JRE listed as well.

Comment: I don't think installing the SDK fixes the "net_rim_os not found" problem though.  At least it doesn't for me - I always get that popup when doing a debug install to a device, and I've got the appropriate SDK installed.